# How to set Meta-Function key combination in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'd need to redefine keyboard mappings of Vim in non-gui mode.

I simply don't understand why the following command does not work:

```
:set <M-F5>=^[[15~

"E518: Unknown option: <M-F5>=^[[15~"
```

whereas mapping of alone F5 key or Meta with non-function key does work:

```
:set <F5>=^[[15~

"ok"

:set <M-space>=^[[15~

"ok"
```

How to redefine Alt/Meta with function keys F1-F12 in Vim ?

Thx in an advance.

David

**Update: Question correction**
In my .vimrc I have the following key-combination mapping

```
autocmd Filetype python noremap <buffer> <silent> <M-F9> :w !pylint -E %<CR>
```

but it does work only in gVim.
It unfortunately does not work in non-gui version of Vim, because Vim recieves escape sequence "^[[20~" instead of direct Meta-F9 keycode.

Comment: Really `set` can be used to map keys? I use `map`. `:map <Ctrl+V><Desired_key_combination> <commands>`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I did mean resetting keycode-combination, not mapping. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from Vim wiki:

```
inoremap <M-i> <Tab>
```

Take a look here:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key

In case that doesn't work, try this:

```
inoremap <ESC>i <Tab>
```

Note this is a hack and will yield a few wierd things that you will just probably have to live with.

For function keys, something like this should work:

```
nnoremap <ESC><F9> :ls<CR>
```

Comment: I'm affraid this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: OK, let me see if I understand - you want to redefine keys like Alt-F1 and such to perform some action? If so, you can use something like `:nnoremap <ESC><F3> :ls<CR>` to map Alt-F3 to list all buffers. Is that what you wanted or not?

Comment: I have generally mapped with noremap <M-F9> key-combination to run some action. It does work in GUI mode (gVim) because it maps Alt/Meta key directly. However vim in Xterm (non-gui) recognizes Meta keypress as an escape sequence. I need to SET <M-F9> to escape sequence and THEN map it.

Comment: I've found the solution but only from Meta-a to Meta-z keybindings. How to extend it for function keys F1-F12 ? >>> the code >>> " Remap broken meta-keys that send ^[
for n in range(97,122) " ASCII a-z
    let c = nr2char(n)
    exec "set <M-". c .">=\e". c
    exec "map  \e". c ." <M-". c .">"
    exec "map! \e". c ." <M-". c .">"
endfor

Comment: I use Vim everyday with meta keys mapped as I suggested and it works just fine. No `set` involved in mapping. I do not use function keys, though, as all of them are mapped to Gnome actions anyway (e.g. Alt-F2 opens Run application dialog, Alt-F7 is window move, etc.). If you try `:map <ESC>q :ls<CR>`, it works properly (i.e. Alt-q becomes the shortcut for invoking `:ls`). Try it out in terminal and confirm that it works. Maybe my point is - Meta mapping works fine, I also know mapping function keys works fine alone, so the only thing that may be wrong is their combination.

Comment: I did tried by your example :map <ESC>F9 :ls<CR> but it does not work, ie. it does not list files in current directory. It looks function keys have to be handled in other way. Vim recognizes <M-q>, <M-space>, <M-X> but not <M-F1>, <M-F2> whereas <C-F1>, <C-F2> or <S-F1> and <S-F2> are ok. Weird.

Comment: I would add I'm using vanilla Vim ver. 7.3 .

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad - it should be `:map <ESC><F9> :ls<CR>` - try this. Vim does recognize function keys - I am using things like `:map <F9> :ls<CR>` daily (try to confirm). Again - meta works, function keys work, the only thing I am not using is meta-function key combination.

Comment: The <ESC><F9> did it. Thank you !